# MVC app at root IIS site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Using VS 2013 with MVC 5 on IIS 7. Built a website using Microsoft's default scaffolding. Our app works great as a virtual folder under an IIS site. But moving to prod we want the app to be at the root domain.

When we go to production, we want http://ourapp.com and not devserver.com/ourapp.

When we are browsing to http://ourapp.com we are getting the IIS7 start page instead of being routed to the application start page.

This is our route config code (we do not use the Home controller):
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you just dropped your app folders and files directly in wwwroot. You can technically do this, but as long as the index.html file is there, that will always be what's hit if you just go to the domain `http://ourapp.com`. Just remove that file, and you should be good.

However, the better way to handle this is to have a separate directory for your application and then create a new site in IIS, pointing to that directory. Just ensure that IIS_USR has access to it. Bind the domain to that site in IIS, and you're good to go.

If neither of those work, then you're probably missing ASP.NET. You can install that from Programs and Features in the Control Panel. Select the "Change Windows Features" link and then browse through the tree of feature options until you see it.

Comment: Interesting, the one part of the equation I didn't mention seems to be what is tripping me up. I did setup a second website and shut off default. Your thoughts gave me the idea of testing using http://localhost and it worked.